# Don't add meeting to a calendar automatically in Microsoft Outlook

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2013

I have Outlook 2013 installed. When someone sends me a meeting request it's automatically added to my calendar and is shown in grey there. When that meeting starts, I receive a notification even if I confirmed nothing. This is super annoying.

Is there any way to switch this feature off and add items to my calendar only when I explicitely ask it?

Answer (score 2):

When you get an Outlook invitation, it goes temporarily into your calendar. That is what you are seeing.

You do have to do something with an Invitation - you cannot do nothing.

Decline the Invitation and Send Response and the calendar invite disappears and nothing more about this meeting will happen.

Accept the Invitation and Send Response and the calendar Invite will become permanent.

So just action the Invitation and invites will work just fine.

Comment: Yes, usually I would make an action but when you have some mail transfer rules from other accounts one not need to action on those meeting requests from another account. The idea is to see in my calendar only the stuff I added there and not the stuff Outlook puts there.

Comment: Most invites work best on one account. If you move the invite, you can still delete it. You need to delete all invites that you do not want. That is how Outlook works.

Comment: Agree with john, we could delete them via filter or others in Outlook, which could make your calendar more clearer and work better.

Answer (score 2):

Not a direct answer, but may help.

To filter the Calendar view:

1. Navigate to the Calendar tab
2. Click `View Settings` from the Ribbon
3. From the dialogue, click `Filter`
4. Go to the `Advanced` tab
5. From the `Field` selector, go to `Frequently-used fields` > `Meeting Status`
6. Set the `Condition` as `equals`, and the `Value` as `Not yet responded`
7. Click `OK` to close the filter dialogue, and `OK` to close the `Advanced View Settings` dialogue

Your calendar now won't show events you've not responded to.

You **will** still see reminders though. I've not found a way around this, yet.

Comment: Those reminders are 90% of the problem. That's super annyoing when you have meetings from 3 accounts and when you ignore 70% of them :)

Comment: Perhaps the best thing to do is decline them then, if you have no intention of attending? You won't get a reminder to attend a meeting you declined...

Comment: I have 3 accounts and the mail transfer. If you send an intitation to `mail@some.mail` and receive a decline from `totallyDifferentMail@some.mail` you'll be surprised. 
I can also remove them manually but I had a hope for some authomatic solution.

Answer (score 1):

To prevent Outlook from automatically adding events to the calendar:

- Go to *File > Options*
- Click *Mail*
- Scroll down to the *Tracking* section
- Disable "Automatically process meeting requests and responses to meeting requests and polls"
- Click OK.

Comment: For me it's already disabled but meetings are still added to the calendar automatically.

Comment: Same for me, it seems to only work for any version of Outlook client.

Comment: Pretty sure this only prevents Tentative meetings showing up in your calendar if you are using Outlook with POP or IMAP. not native Exchange connection (because then they are processes server-side?)